# How to order records by id ascendingly after ordering it by the other column if 2 records have the same column's value? - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting, activerecord

I have a Product table like this

```
id name display_order
------------------------
1   A    2
2   B    4
3   C    4
4   D    1
```

After order it by display_order desc the result looks like this:

```rb
Product.order(display_order: :desc)
```

```
id name display_order
------------------------
3   C    4
2   B    4
1   A    2
4   D    1
```

Now I want to keep this order, but if two or more products have the same display_order, I want them to be ordered by id ascendingly like this:

```
id name display_order
------------------------
2   B    4
3   C    4
1   A    2
4   D    1
```

Do you know any rails or ruby syntax or algorithm can help me achieve this result? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it easily using SQL:

```
Product.order(display_order: :desc, id: :asc)
```

It's translated to something like

```
select products.* from products order by products.display_order desc, products.id asc
```

Comment: [This rails documentation](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/order) also provides examples of ordering on multiple columns.

Comment: What does 'it didn't work' mean in your case? What happened?

Comment: What exactly did you try? What result did you get? What result did you expect? What do you mean by *didn't work*?